# How to mock JobExecution.builder() using mockito and mock DynamoDBMapper for unit testing?

Tags: java, unit-testing, amazon-dynamodb, mockito

I want to test below method using mockito. jobExecution object is saved in DynamoDB. Please refer the code below.

```
private void saveOrUpdateToDynamoDb(final JobExecution existingJobExecution) {
final JobExecution jobExecution = JobExecution.builder().jobMasterId("12").jobType("lamda")
                    .jobAction("Entry message load into MC").status("running").startDate(startTime).referenceId("225")
                        .payload(messageBody).ttlExpiry(5259600+Instant.now().getEpochSecond()).build();
saveOrUpdateToDynamoDb(jobExecution);
}

private void saveOrUpdateToDynamoDb(final JobExecution existingJobExecution) {
    dbMapper.save(existingJobExecution,
                    new TableNameOverride(String.format(STRING_CONCAT, CAPABILITY_CODE, envName, TABLE_NAME)).config());
}
```

Comment: Usually the goal of mocking is to `hard code` functionality during the tests. What functionality are you looking to hard-code? I am guessing you are looking to mock the dbMapper.save(***) since your DB may not exist at test time, is that correct?

Comment: yes  I have to mock dbMapper @Bend

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to mock `saveOrUpdateToDynamoDb` so that method could be called during tests, without actually trying to connect to the DB, you could do something like this:

```
public class Foo {

    // @VisibleForTesting makes it obvious why this is package-private, not private
    @VisibleForTesting
    DynamoDBMapper dbMapper = ***

    private void saveOrUpdateToDynamoDb(final JobExecution existingJobExecution) {
        final JobExecution jobExecution = JobExecution.builder().jobMasterId("12").jobType("lamda")
            .jobAction("Entry message load into MC").status("running").startDate(startTime).referenceId("225")
            .payload(messageBody).ttlExpiry(5259600+Instant.now().getEpochSecond()).build();
        saveOrUpdateToDynamoDb(jobExecution);
    }

    @VisibleForTesting
    void saveOrUpdateToDynamoDb(final JobExecution existingJobExecution) {
        dbMapper.save(existingJobExecution,
            new TableNameOverride(String.format(STRING_CONCAT, CAPABILITY_CODE, envName, TABLE_NAME)).config());
    }

}
```

Then in your tests (which should be in the same package)

```
    @Test
    void testXYZ() {
        doNothing().when(foo.saveOrUpdateToDynamoDb(any(JobExecution.class)));

        // test now
    }

    //OR
    @Test
    void testXYZ() {
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.dbMapper = mock(DynamoDBMapper.class);

        doNothing().when(foo.dbMapper.save(any(JobExecution.class), any(TableNameOverride.class)));

        // test now
    }
```

To the calling code, this will look like a successful DB save.

Comment: Unable to add @VisibleForTesting in the actual class. Also I have to mock dbMapper in order to call dbMapper.save(existingJobExecution,
            new TableNameOverride(String.format(STRING_CONCAT, CAPABILITY_CODE, envName, TABLE_NAME)).config()); . Please provide a solution for that.

Comment: @VisibleForTesting is in Google's Guava package, and has no functionality associated with it, it is just informative to future developers. So, not a big deal.

edited answer with dbMapper.save mock